# Deleting rows from a very large database with no index

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing, sql-delete

We got a message from our hardware team telling us that a database is taking 1.4 TB of space alone. We looked at it and it has several tables with millions of entries of historic data (a trigger loads the last 4 years of logs, everyday, for some reason, and not deleting data at all). And it has no index.

We want to delete the old data, but we cannot figure out how without melting the machine, a simple COUNT took 15 minutes, adding an index or trying to do anything big is going to fail.

The only idea we are thinking of now is creating a temporary table, store the data we want to save in small batches and then truncate the old one.

So far we are trying the select part of this code as a test.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT TOP (1000) *
FROM table
ORDER BY year DESC
)
DELETE FROM CTE
```

It takes even longer to select the values, with the amount of data we are looking at we expect to cleanse the table in more than 7 years.

EDIT: the question is how to clear the useless data. The table taking so much space is a problem
EDIT2: Changed the term to temporary table. For clarification: creating a new table to dump the info we want to keep. Then later, deleting it.

Comment: Not seeing a question?

Comment: FYI, SQL Server 2008 ran *completely* out of support over **4 years ago**. It is *long* past time you implemented that upgrade plan you, presumably, finalised several years ago. Using such an old version, which has received *no* security patches for so long is a significant risk to your environment and clients.

Comment: i think your idea is fine.:rename the old table, create new table with old name, then create an index for data you wanna save and then copy the data from old to new table. you don't need a clustered index, just an index on year or whatever else you need to find the needed rows. it shouldn't take that long even for *millions* of rows and you can use it for batch inserts

Comment: *"The only idea we are thinking of now is creating a temporal table"* You won't be able to create a temporal table, that feature was added in SQL Server 2016. Though I'm not sure how a temporal table will help you here either; you are trying to reduce the size of the table, and temporal table store not just the *current* version of the row, but all historical versions of it as well.

Comment: You say you have *no* indexes; does this mean you don't even have a `CLUSTERED INDEX`? The table is in a HEAP?

Comment: @ThomA I know the server is too old, I cannot do anything about that. 


By temporal table I meant a regular table that is going to be deleted later, as SQL server 2008 does not have a true temporal table. 


The table has no PK, no index made, nothing to properly use like that. I did not know the term heap, but it seems to fit that definition.

Comment: Do you mean a *temporary* table? Temporal and temporary objects are completely different.

Comment: Could be, English is not my main language and I could not differenciate the terms properly. Sorry about the missunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about about data older than 4 years in this archive table (it's not clear in your question), then:

- Disable the trigger.
- Script out the CREATE TABLE statement for the table.
- DROP the table.
- Re-create the table.
- Enable the trigger. After it fires* and re-loads 4 years of data...
- Disable the trigger. Change the trigger to load yesterday's data only.
- Create an SQL Server Job to delete data older than 4 years (or whatever number of years you require) from the archive table.

*What I don't understand is:

1. How is an SQL Server Trigger getting fired to copy 4 years of data?
2. Why are you copying the most current 4 years?

You might be better served copying anything older than 4 years from the source table to the archive table, in which case the SQL Server Job referenced above would instead copy anything older than `X` years from the source table to the archive table, and then delete that data from the source table. You'd also need to determine how long to keep the data in the archive table. But you didn't provide those requirements in your question.

Comment: The trigger is a daily rutine, each day at 8:00 fires itself. No one knows why we need to save so much duplicate data, it's been years since it has been used and we actually use a proper log for our checks. Mind that this a project where several companies took the lead and each one of them clustered the database with their own way of making things.

Comment: I forgot. The table (lets call it 2) where this table (1) takes the data from works like you say: loads logs, filters 4 years, deletes data older than 4 years. 1 is just a copy of 2 but without deleting the data each day... I feel stupid just speaking this out loud. You are right, i did not provide those requirements because we do not have them and we should. I am going to explain this to the manager, and see if I overcome his fear of the possibility of breaking something.

Comment: You can also propose, to ease the manager's fear, creating a new, *third* table for the archive, with proper limited data. Then, when the manager is comfortable with Table 3 working just fine, DROP Table 2. Yes, it is more short-term storage use, but it provides peace of mind.

Comment: I managed to make him delete the data of the table, but he refused to touch the code of the trigger or the structure of the table, as it was not our code. "Not my job" comes to mind about this issue, but thanks anyway as it was a good idea.